# How would I say "beauty"?

Tags: translation

I'm doing a project for my Mandarin class, and we're designing a mall. One of the components I want to include is a level for health and beauty, like makeup, etc. I've looked up translations of "beauty", but they all seem to be referring to a person, like a woman who is beautiful.

How would you say "beauty" in the context above?

Comment: feed "health and beauty" to jukuu,e.g.  **健美**  杂志 h&b magazine,  **健美容**  品 h&b products,   **保健与美容**   零售集团 h&b retailer,   **保健和美容**  业 h&b world, etc. for beauty alone 美容 seems possible

Comment: comment #1 based on "designing a mall", therefore "beauty" as in beauty parlor,beauty salon; lady's hair parlor   **美容院**  , 美容 also occurs in 
美容女/美容师, hairdresser, beautician (female/male),美容店 beauty salon,美容手术 cosmetic surgery,
re: comment #2:  环保 environmental protection; environmentally friendly 美观 pleasing to the eye; beautiful; artistic.

Comment: usually 美妆、个护健康 (个护 is 个人护理)

Comment: health and beauty, for a building, it is 环保和美观

Answer (score 1, accepted):

美妝would be the all encompassing term. It's a general term for beauty and cosmetics, with beauty being things like hair accessories, makeup applicators, etc. 
If it is a department store you're designing, you'd likely break it down into more specific categories such as cosmetics, hair care, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

“美容” is the best translation I can find in your context.
Literally, it means "beautify faces".

Answer (score 0):

Health and beauty literally mean 健康 与 美丽. 美丽 can describe everything beautiful, not just specific to a person.

As a product of makeup, you could also consider 天然 纯净, meaning natural and pure, because natural and pure things stand for health. There are some other words you can reference: 清爽, 自然，白嫩，青春，靓丽，活力

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that OP is looking for a term to call the "beauty products" section of a mall. They are looking for a noun like 美容(品), not any of your suggestions above.

Comment: @as4s4hetic, ok, let OP clarify it. In fact, I am not quite sure what OP really wants here. So, I just offered these words in case he/she might use.

Comment: Originally, I thought the OP just wanted some words to describe the products.